# Qt Release QProcess Signal Slot Issue

Tags: qt, signals, release, qprocess, slot

Using **Qt 5.6.0 & MSVC2015** I have an app which upon start-up, using QProcess and ssh/plink/cat, shall attempt to read the hostname of a remote server and capture the contents of a specific file on a remote server.  This **works when run from Qt Creator (the IDE), in either debug or release**.  If I attempt the same app from outside if Qt Creator, either the signal is never emitted or the slot is not called.

Here's the pertinent code bits:

```
void MainWindow::Perform1stSSHcmd()
{
    QPalette palette;
    // hostname: THIS IS OUR 1st SSH COMMAND SO WE WANT TO DETERMINE IF THE KEYS ARE SET UP OK...
    QProcess* qp = new QProcess( this );
    QString userAndCommand = "root@";
    userAndCommand.append( m_cmsIp );
    userAndCommand.append(" hostname"); // cmd we want to execute on the remote server

    qp->start( m_plinkPuttyCmd.arg( userAndCommand  ));
    qp->waitForFinished( 16000 ); // I've tried vaious values for this
    QString output = qp->readAll();
    QString err = qp->readAllStandardError();
    // ... SNIP various error checking here ...

    // Now the system info
    m_sysInfoProc = new QProcess(this);

    qDebug() << "About to read systemInfo.xml... ";
    if( !connect( this->m_sysInfoProc, SIGNAL( readyReadStandardOutput() ), SLOT( readSystemInfoXML() ))) {
        qDebug() << "Connect Failed!!!!!";
    }
    userAndCommand = "root@";
    userAndCommand.append( m_cmsIp );
    qDebug() << "preparing cat of xml... ";
    userAndCommand.append(" cat /root/systemInfo.xml");
    m_sysInfoProc->start( m_plinkPuttyCmd.arg( userAndCommand  ));

    qDebug() << "->start issued... ";
    m_sysInfoProc->waitForFinished( 6000 );
    qDebug() << "after waitForFinished( 6000 )";
}


void MainWindow::readSystemInfoXML()
{
    qDebug() << "In readSystemInfoXML()";

    QProcess *systemInfoXml = qobject_cast<QProcess *>(sender());
    if( !systemInfoXml ) {
        return;
    }

    QString res = systemInfoXml->readAllStandardOutput();
    qDebug() << "readSystemInfoXML() just read:" << res;
    if( !res.length() ) {
        return;
    }
    // . . . XML parsing of file contents . . . (not a concern, works fine)
}
```

### Output Debug/Releas Mode from IDE:

Wed Sep 28 15:36:06 2016 Debug: output:  "Lanner" 
Wed Sep 28 15:36:06 2016 Debug: err:  "" 
Wed Sep 28 15:36:06 2016 Debug: About to read systemInfo.xml... 
Wed Sep 28 15:36:06 2016 Debug: preparing cat of xml... 
Wed Sep 28 15:36:06 2016 Debug: ->start issued... 
Wed Sep 28 15:36:06 2016 Debug: In readSystemInfoXML()
Wed Sep 28 15:36:06 2016 Debug: readSystemInfoXML() just read: "\n  \n\t2.50-06-15\n        1.0\n \tSINA\n \tclass IC\n \tdoes something\n \n"
Wed Sep 28 15:36:06 2016 Debug: after waitForFinished( 6000 )
Wed Sep 28 15:36:06 2016 Debug: ICICIC

(tags missing from xml dur to formatting, only values appear)

Now the release...

## Output when started from release folder on my Windows box:

Wed Sep 28 15:38:09 2016 Debug: output:  "" 
Wed Sep 28 15:38:09 2016 Debug: err:  ""
Wed Sep 28 15:38:09 2016 Debug: About to read systemInfo.xml... 
Wed Sep 28 15:38:09 2016 Debug: preparing cat of xml... 
Wed Sep 28 15:38:09 2016 Debug: ->start issued... 
Wed Sep 28 15:38:09 2016 Debug: after waitForFinished( 6000 )
Wed Sep 28 15:38:09 2016 Debug: ICICIC

I've searched for others who may of had similar issues, the closest was
[Qt: some slots don't get executed in release mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689059/qt-some-slots-dont-get-executed-in-release-mode)

I've tried touching MainWindow.h, re-running qmake and build all, no luck.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Ian

Comment: You don't appear to perform any error/status checking whatsoever on `m_sysInfoProc`.

Comment: Why do you ask us where the problem is? You have all the information you need to figure out what's wrong. You're just not looking at it... when you pretend that everything has succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: As it turns out it was related to the way ssh caches keys, more specifically my app's processing of QProcess' output.